# IFrame on Silverllight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to add IFrame to my Silverlight web site. and into that iframe i want to add aspx page. is that possible? (aspx page in silverlight.)

Answer (score 1):

It's posible in your HTML where you call the Silverlight xap file, but not inside Silverlight itself

Comment: when run my project silverlight its opening. there menu on project. when click about us, I want to show my aspx page <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" /> inside this

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add what ever asp / html elements to the web page where your silverlight application is running.

For example modify the ProjectNameTestPage.aspx in your web project.

Comment: Example? I guess you don't fully understand my reply. I'll try to clarify. When you are developing your Silverlight project you have a web project too in the solution, right? You can find a aspx page in there named after your project name. This is the page that will be fired when you run your project. Modify that page by adding the IFrame and aspx you want. Or if you can use an existing URL address for the aspx project you can try to use the browser control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to have HTML content nested within the Silverlight, Telerik for example has a control called "HtmlWindow" or "RadWindow" which does just this. Either you could subscribe to their control set or try and find out how they did it.

I have used Telerik's control multiple times in an MEF Silverlight application where different web applications (SSRS for example) are contained with the MEF plugins.